react-leaflet-heatmap-layer-v3 src directory not found
Trying to use the npm library react-leaflet-heatmap-layer-v3 and after I install it successfully and then yarn start my react typescript app, I get the following warning messages:
WARNING in ./node_modules/react-leaflet-heatmap-layer-v3/lib/Heatmap.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/client/node_modules/react-leaflet-heatmap-layer-v3/src/Heatmap.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/client/node_modules/react-leaflet-heatmap-layer-v3/src/Heatmap.ts'

WARNING in ./node_modules/react-leaflet-heatmap-layer-v3/lib/HeatmapLayer.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/client/node_modules/react-leaflet-heatmap-layer-v3/src/HeatmapLayer.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/client/node_modules/react-leaflet-heatmap-layer-v3/src/HeatmapLayer.ts'

WARNING in ./node_modules/react-leaflet-heatmap-layer-v3/lib/index.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/client/node_modules/react-leaflet-heatmap-layer-v3/src/index.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/client/node_modules/react-leaflet-heatmap-layer-v3/src/index.ts'

When I go and check the node_modules for this library, there is no "src" directory but there is a "lib" directory that has all these files.
Am I missing something or doing something wrong as I need to use this library together with "react-leaflet": "^4.2.1" in my package.json
Do I need to use an earlier version of react-leaflet inorder for this to work?

For anyone that might be facing the same issue, I ended up removing this react-leaflet-heatmap-layer-v3 package and replaced it with @vgrid/react-leaflet-heatmap-layer
It required a few changes but all is now fine.
